# converting list to data frame with specific column names

Tags: r

converting list to data frame with specific column names in R

[image]

The 'dataframe' I want is as follows.

[image]

Comment: Try with `do.call(cbind, lst1)` or `do.call(rbind, lst1)`

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). It might help to make this question *reproducible*. This includes sample code (including listing non-base R packages), sample *unambiguous* data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(x=...,y=...)`), and expected output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: you can also use `dplyr::bind_rows`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.mylist = as.data.frame(mylist)
names(df.mylist) = c('Time', 'Z1', 'Z2', ... , 'Z10')
df.mylist
```